# Android: Navigation Component - How to connect Toolbar menu to the fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Iv been stuck in trying to add the Navigation Component to my app. Specifically to my toolbar menu items.

I have been following the [navigation migrate](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#move) documentation on Android's site but I am getting a but confused on how it works or even to set it up.

This is a **single-activity multi-fragment** architecture.

The app would start in the MainFragment and then when tapping the menu items in the toolbar, such as Main Frag to Search Movie Frag. The user would be able to navigate using the menu items from anywhere in the app (e.g. if they click the home icon, they should be sent to the home screen form anywhere in the app. Still thinking if thats how it should be done).

The main thing is I don't know how to properly attach the Navigation Component to the menu items.

**App**

[image: Main Fragment displayed on phone]

**Nav Graph**

[image: Nav Graph displayed on Android Studio]

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.movieapp.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_searchMovieFragment"
            app:destination="@id/searchMovieFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchMovieFragment"
        android:name="com.example.movieapp.ui.search.SearchMovieFragment"
        android:label="SearchMovieFragment" />
</navigation>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/appbar"
        android:id="@+id/mainToolBar"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainToolBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private val navController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, null)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu_bar, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**MainFragment.kt**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: MainFragmentBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
//        navController.navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_searchMovieFragment)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

**main_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.movieapp.ui.main.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MainFragment1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The id for a menu item in your file `main_menu_bar.xml` needs to match the id for the destination(fragment) specified in your navigation graph (`nav_graph.xml`).

Your `main_menu_bar.xml` should look something like this:

```kotlin
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@id/searchMovieFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            android:title="@string/menu_search" />
        <item
            android:id="@id/mainFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Also, you need to override the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` method and associate your menu items with destinations. Like so:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)

Comment: Thank you this works @Siddarth! Also, how would I be able to make it so that when the user taps on the Search icon while on the search fragment, it ignores it instead of reloading it?

Comment: @efoc I believe that should already be happening. If not, you can add `if (item.itemId == navController.currentDestination?.id) return true` to the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` method above

Comment: Thank you! It was refreshing the fragment every time it was clicked. This works!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Toolbar on top of the most basic FragmentContainerView, access this toolbar from other fragments, and change the toolbar I created separately according to the fragment in it while opening the relevant fragment as follows.

```
        toolbar = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_base)

        toolbar?.menu?.clear()
        toolbar?.title = ""
        val toolbarFlowFragment = context?.let { getInflateLayout(it, R.layout.toolbar_profile) }

        toolbar?.addView(toolbarFlowFragment)
```